# Deleting empty lines in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice

In Libre office calc I have a bunch of cells that contain empty lines. A single cell looks like this:

[image: breaks]

How can I delete the empty lines from the cells to get cells that look like this:

[image: no breaks]

I do not want to edit 200 cells by hand to delete the blank lines. I'm sure there is a faster way.

P.S. I obtained these cells by copying a table from a website into Libre office calc. For that I used the clip-board.

Comment: I've added two screenshots to illustrate the issue...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you want to remove multiple empty lines in one step if possible. To remove a single line, there's a context menu entry.

There are two possible approaches to remove multiple lines without much hassle:

- as proposed in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/298502/84724): sort the lines alphabetically so the empty lines get sorted to the start or end, then delete them.
- as proposed in [this blog post](http://www.worldstart.com/openoffice-org-calc-removing-blank-rows-from-your-data/): use filtering to get only the blank lines displayed, then select and delete them, then remove the filter.

**EDIT:**

To remove hard line breaks inside cells automatically, you could use the search / replace functionality and regular expressions. Just search for `\n` and let the replace box empty. Don't forget to activate "`Regular expressions`" under <kbd>More Options...</kbd>. You won't see a result immediately, since Calc doesn't change the row height automatically. So you will have to set the row height using `Optimal row height...` in the context menu after removing the line breaks.

[image: search - replace]

**EDIT 2:**

It may be possible that there aren't any empty lines in the cells, so the search/replace operation may fail. This is because LibreOffice automatically applies styles from the original html tables when pasting data from the web. To make sure that it isn't just a row format issue, just select the complete sheet and select `Optimal height...` from Menu `Format` -> `Row`.

Comment: I'm sorry, my question was not very clear. I want to delete empty lines within a cell. I adapted the question.

Comment: ah - ok, i understand. i've emended my answer to cover this.

Comment: @tohuwawohu nice. can this be adapted so that separate text stays seperate? (<text><empty line><text> becomes <texttext>.)

Comment: hmm - this is a little bit difficult, since this depends on the content details of your table. The easiest way would be to replace the `\n` by a single space. But this may result in multiple subsequent spaces or in leading spaces. So, additional search/replace runs using regular expressions may be required.

Answer (score 0):

from Libreoffice help:

*CLEAN

All non-printing characters are removed from the string.
Syntax

CLEAN("Text")

Text refers to the text from which to remove all non-printable characters. *

Comment: Good find, but doesn't remove all the line breaks for me. Did you test it? It leaves one hard line break when trying to remove multiple subsequent line breaks.

Comment: Someone must have changed the meaning of all.

Answer (score -2):

Download LO Calc guide [here](http://wiki.documentfoundation.org/images/6/6d/0300CG3-CalcGuideLibO3.pdf) and go to page 31!

Comment: Did you mean Page 31? Maybe you should add the relevant information to your answer, since if the link gets invalid, your answer gets useless, too.